# SQL multiple LIKE not working in cakephp OR

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

When I am trying this code this is working fine for phone field.

```
       $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                    'conditions' =>array( 'OR'=>array(
                                    array('user.id'=>$search),
                                    array('user.email' =>$email),
                                    array('user.phone LIKE' =>'%'.$phone.'%'),
                                    array('user.name_kana' =>$sname),
                                    array('user.name' =>$name),
                            )),
                    'limit'=>4
        );
```

But if I try multiple LIKE nothing is working, it's fetching all result.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
                    'conditions' =>array( 'OR'=>array(
                                    array('user.id'=>$search),
                                    array('user.email LIKE' =>'%'.$email.'%'),
                                    array('user.phone LIKE' =>'%'.$phone.'%'),
                                    array('user.name_kana' =>$sname),
                                    array('user.name' =>$name),
                            )),
                    'limit'=>4
       );
```

Is there any wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked what SQL is being produced by the paginator?

Comment: Please post the generated SQL, some sample data, and your expected/actual results. There's no way we can answer this question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' =>array( 'OR'=>array(
         "user.id"=>$search,
         "user.email LIKE" =>'%'.$email.'%',
         "user.phone LIKE" =>'%'.$phone.'%',
         "user.name_kana" =>$sname,
         "user.name" =>$name,
     )),
     'limit'=>4
);
```

Hope this will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

> Please  try this CODE

```
  $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'conditions' =>array( 'OR'=>array(
                                array('user.id'=>$search),
                                array('user.email LIKE' =>"%$email%"),
                                array('user.phone LIKE' =>"%$phone%"),
                                array('user.name_kana' =>$sname),
                                array('user.name' =>$name),
                        )),
                'limit'=>4
    );
```